# Adding up (SUM) the values of a field in an entries loop

Tags: stash, math

I have an ee entries loop returning a bunch of entries. Each entry has a custom field holding a numerical value. I would like to add together the values of that field at the end and output the total.

PHP equivalent would be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
$total += $value[$i];
}


Total = echo $total
```

Even better would be to just have this run a SQL like command and return the value for me:

SELECT SUM(column) FROM table

Are there any plugins that can help me with this? I'd like to avoid PHP if possible but if I have to how would I make the PHP work with EE tags, I can't seem to get the value for the custom field into my PHP.

Is there an operator for Stash to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use a plugin to do this.

I think http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tally  will do the trick.

I hope this will help u.

Regard's.

Comment: This is exactly what I need but I can't get it to work. Will post the code below.

Comment: I posted up to the official support forum if you are interested: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/tally/viewthread/12825

Comment: Hi, I see your post , You just need to put the second part in embed template. if this works with you please accept my answer here. Regard's.